# How do you simplify this expression to show it follows an exponential distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to show that W = ln(X) - ln(α) follows an exponential distribution where I am using the Pareto distribution as the primary function.

The Pareto PDF is $f(x;α,φ) = \frac{φα^φ}{x^{φ+1}}$, x > α.

I have used the change of variable method to find the inverse of W, which is $X = e^w+α = g^{-1}(w)$, with $\frac{dx}{dw} = e^w$

After substituting $g^{-1}(w)$ into the Pareto PDF and multiplying by $\frac{dx}{dw}$ , I obtained $\frac{e^wφα^φ}{(e^w+α)^{φ+1}}$.

My question is: How do I simplify that expression to show it follows an exponential distribution? Algebra is one of my weak points.

Comment: Is that the correct inverse? It looks to me that it should be $\alpha\exp(w)$? Then, glancing at the Pareto PDF, things should simplify nicer.

Comment: @TrostAft if you add ln(α) to both sides, you get ln(α) + W = ln(X). Then, by exponentiating both sides, you obtain α + e^W = X

Comment: $\exp(\log(\alpha) + W) = \exp(\log(\alpha))\exp(W) = \alpha \exp(W)$, correct?

Comment: Ahhh, I see! I made a silly mistake. Thank you for pointing that out, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think after you correct your inverse the problem will seem much less painful.
$$
W = \log(X) - \log(\alpha) \implies
\exp(W + \log(\alpha)) = X
\implies
\alpha \exp(W) = X
$$
Good luck!